# twilio get conference participants information from conference SID name in php

Tags: php, api, twilio, phone-call, twilio-php

I am creating a application which use twilio conference, I am able to get conference SID using below code

```
$client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '123');
foreach ($client->account->conferences->getIterator(0, 50, array(
   'FriendlyName' => 'yourConf'
)) as $conf) {
    print $conf->sid;
}
```

Now I want all participate SID so that i am able to proceed ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here again :)

Once you have the Conference SID, you can get the participants like this:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '123');
foreach ($client->account->conferences->getIterator(0, 50, array(
   'FriendlyName' => 'yourConf'
)) as $conf) {
    print $conf->sid;
    $participants = $client->account->conferences->get(sid)->participants
    foreach ($participants as $participant) {
        // Do something with the participant
    }
}
```

You can see [the documentation and examples for this method in the Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#list-get-filters).

Comment: i have tried the above method but still i am able to get only last participate information. But in my conference then are two participate and conference is also running properly

Comment: Can you share the code you've written that is only getting you one participant?